# how to fix "Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'."?

Tags: java, android, windows, flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @31ba7dae

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 30s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     845,3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location** and under **JDK Location** make sure you have the *Embedded JDK* location instead of *JAVA_HOME*. For me the path is `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`